# Control Excerpt depending on title length

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to control the length of the excerpt depending on title length?

I mean, supposee you have a title length of 25 characters and it will put 20 characters of excerpt but if you have 10 characters in title it puts 30 characaters..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there a total number of characters that you're looking for? 25+20 is 45, while 10 + 30 is 40.

Comment: Not exactly, it doesnt matter it could be any arbitrary combination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is within the loop:

```
function createExcerpt(){

    $title = get_the_title();
    $content = get_the_content();

    if ( strlen($title) > 24 ){
      $custom_excerpt = substr($content, 0, 25);
    }

    else {
      $custom_excerpt = substr($content, 0, 30);
    }

    return $custom_excerpt;

}

echo createExcerpt() . ' (...)';
```

Comment: what you mean by assuming this within the loop?

Comment: Within the WordPress loop.  get_the_title() and get_the_content() won't necessarily work as expect outside the loop.

Comment: really noob here, just tested it putted in the article code i guess thats what u mean..

Comment: In the article code?  Do you mean in the WSIWYG wordpress editor?  That won't work. If you're putting it right into an article, it'll need to be a short code.

Comment: no, i mean in the part where it used to say "the_excerpt" ahahha. Again real noob, im just putting it in the php

Comment: is it posible to make it return with a 3 dots(...) in the end?

Comment: Yes, it will now add three dots.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    echo substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40); 
?>

<?php 
    if (strlen($post->post_title) > 40) {
        echo substr(the_title($before = '', $after = '', FALSE), 0, 40) . '...'; 
    } else {
        the_title();
    } 
?>
```